# What is the conio.h library used for? C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program watching a lot of videos so my program has so many libraries that I don't remember what some of them are for. Could someone be so kind as to tell me perhaps some of the uses of the following libraries?

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<stdlib.h>
//#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h> 
//#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h> //Sleep
#include<locale.h>
#include<cstdio>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Comment: you can simply uncommented them and see what error comes out. (not a good way though, you'd better know what you want when you include)

Comment: google each one and you will get lot of tutorials.

Comment: Because DOS existed 35 years ago. It is 100% non-portable to anything other than DOS/Windows. It holds `getch()` which does input in raw (non-canonical) mode. If that is what is required, use it -- that's the way DOS/Windows does non-canonical mode) Otherwise, you will have to use some OS specific function like `tcsetattr` on Linux. If you are just using it to hold the terminal window open, then use `getchar()` from `stdio.h` and make your code portable. (better, conditionally include the last `getchar()` by checking if `_WIN32` is defined)

Comment: Setting `<conio.h>` aside for the moment (and preferably for good), there are several online references which cover the Standard C++ Library. I would recommend either [cplusplus.com](https://cplusplus.com/reference/) or [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) as a starting point. A good reference book would also be desirable.

Comment: Note that `<windows.h>` is a header for a wide variety of Microsoft Windows-specific functions, and, like `<conio.h>`, it isn't part of the Standard C++ Library. Also, some of the headers you mention (`<locale.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, `<string.h>`) are from the Standard C library, and have C++ equivalents prepended with a `c` and with the `.h` extension removed - `<clocale>`, `<cstdio>`, `<cstdlib>`, `<cstring>`. Conversely, `<string>` without the `c` is the C++ `string` class, and `<iostream>` is the C++ stream I/O classes and standard objects such as `cout` and `cin`.

Answer (score 3):

The `conio.h` library is not a C/C++ Standard Library. It's a collection of Windows-specific functions. Most commonly people use `_kbhit` or `_getch` to continue a 'paused' console application when a user hits a key on the keyboard.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/console-and-port-i-o

It also defined some legacy MS-DOS functions like `_inp` and `_outp` which are not in the modern Microsoft C/C++ Runtime Library. None of them work in 'user-mode' Windows.